# To add an external css file from the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I've a CSS file, say SomeStyle.css. Is it possible for me to apply this style sheet document to an aspx page from its code behind?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can add literal controls to your header control:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(
    new System.Web.UI.LiteralControl("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"" + ResolveUrl("~/Styles/SomeStyle.css") + "\" />"));
```

Comment: Nice! Compared to WebResources and attached as embedded resources. What would you see as pros / cons?

Comment: Pros - easy. Cons - Any changes require a recompile of the code.

Comment: is there an optimum way i can do it without recompilation? Suppose I have an option to select theme in my page and each theme refer to each different files...

Comment: Go with Matthews and you don't need recompile, if I understand you correct. I was asked about embedded resources. With those, you compile the css into a library.