# Load stylesheet at runtime

Tags: html, asp.net, css, stylesheet

i have specific theme css which is required only when popup window is launches, nowhere else i'm using that css. Simply loading at the launch of website launch is waste.

Is there a way to load css only when required i.e upon opening popup window i can load the stylesheet?.

Comment: You could load it from the codebehind of the aspx page displayed in your popup (cfr [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488678/to-add-an-external-css-file-from-the-code-behind)), or (but it's less clean) put the bit of CSS inside `style`tags in your aspx.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new element like this

```
var lnk=document.createElement('link');
lnk.href='path/sheet.css';
lnk.rel='stylesheet';
lnk.type='text/css';
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(lnk);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Chandaniitr thanks for your help, here 'link' means what?. and if i have 2 stylesheets, then i need to repeat the same code twice with different params right

Comment: Here, 'link' is the type of element you want to create.
The code will add <link href='path/sheet.css' rel=... >.
And, yes, you have to repeat this 2 times. You can wrap this in a function, something like add_stylesheet('path/sheet.css'). You can also play around with id, and change href, to change style-sheet at run-time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this approach [How to load up CSS files using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574944/how-to-load-up-css-files-using-javascript) (the code below)

But it does add a significant amount of stuffing to the site, maybe the CSS takes up less space anyway?

```
var $ = document; // shortcut
var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!$.getElementById(cssId))
{
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'http://website.com/css/stylesheet.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
}
```

Comment: Worth noting also that the $ variable is used by a number of popular JS libraries, including jQuery, so you may want to try a different one/just using document itself if you are using any of those.

Comment: Alex thanks for your answer, this code i need to place at the start of my website popup page javascript right

Comment: in this what does var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id.. this line do, can you explain us

Comment: If you would like the ID to be guaranteed unique and/or can be remembered, you could use the path as an ID itself, so for instance set the ID to be website_com_css_stylesheet_css or similar. I think that is what he meant. But you don't need to do this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your code behind using [GetWebResourceUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl.aspx)

```
HtmlLink css= new HtmlLink();
css.Href = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "yourstyle.css");
css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

Or

```
Literal cssFile = new Literal() 
          {Text = @"<link href=""" + page.ResolveUrl("~yourstyle.css") + @"""  
            type=""text/css"" rel=""stylesheet"" />" };
page.Header.Controls.Add(cssFile);
```

Comment: Hi murali, thank you for your help. I would like to know yourstyle.css is just css file name or do i need to provide relative path?

Comment: @LLL, The `GetWebResourceUrl()` will find the url for the filename supplied

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the jQuery way:

`$('head').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='/href' type='text/css' anythingelse='value' />");`